# Bazel remote cache on a local disk

Tags: bazel

I'm trying to better understand and leverage remote caching.

I'm running *bazel build* in a docker container, while specifying remote cache directory on a local disk:

```
docker run --rm -it -v $PWD:/work -w /work bazel:latest \
  bazel build --disk_cache=.bazel-disk-cache //...
```

At the end of this run, the remote cache is populated in the *.bazel-disk-cache* directory on the local disk.

Then I ran the same command again. This time it is a new container instance with an empty local cache, but the remote cache is present. However, it took almost the same amount of time to complete the task, as the first run.

Is that expected? I was hoping to reduce the build time when using remote cache. What do I miss?

Answer (score 0):

I did the following and did experience a reduced build time

Start the Bazel Remote Cache with Docker with the metrics endpoint enabled

```
docker run -u 1000:1000 -v $(pws)/bzl-cache:/data -p 9090:8080 -p 9092:9092 buchgr/bazel-remote-cache --max_size 5 --enable_endpoint_metrics
```

Check the Bazel Remote Cache container IP address

```
docker inspect -f '{{range.NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' <CONTAINER_ID>
# assuming it is 172.17.0.2
```

Check the current status of the cache

```
curl 172.17.0.2:8080/status
```

This returns something like (different numbers depending on your setup and already populated data in the Bazel Remote Cache)

```
{
    "CurrSize": 7651328,
    "UncompressedSize": 18616320,
    "ReservedSize": 0,
    "MaxSize": 5368709120,
    "NumFiles": 14,
    "ServerTime": 1690295548,
    "GitCommit": "dc4aeace0af5b893c96bd994a816dfbaba9b18c2",
    "NumGoroutines": 9
}
```

Next spinnup another container and build something with Bazel, I compiled `redis` (a local thing)

```
bazel build --remote_cache=http://172.17.0.2:8080 @redis//:build
```

The Bazel Remote Cache will report several PUT requests and data will be placed in the cache. In my case it took round about 2 minutes to complete. After that I cleaned the local things and called build again

```
bazel clean && bazel build --remote_cache=http://172.17.0.2:8080 @redis//:build
```

This time it took only 5 seconds, producing GET requests on the Bazel Remote Cache as all the data got downloaded from there. To produce more load I prepared a bunch of parallel calls to the cache with almost the same result, round about 5 seconds, sometimes 7 seconds due to the load on the cache to handle all the connections.